# Running aspnet web site starts on parent directory

Tags: asp.net, web, vs-web-site-project, asp.net-webpages

I have some old project written in asp.net web pages. I open project by Open Website option and choosing MyCompany folder. I start a project with debugging. The Asp.NET Development server starts.

Actual: `localhost:53669/MyCompany/somepage.aspx`

Expected: `localhost:53669/somepage.aspx`

How can I force the ASP.NET development server to start on MyCompany folder location not on the parent folder location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Visual Studio are you using? In Visual Studio 2010, you can change it in the project properties

Steps

- Open the **Solution Explorer**
- Right click your project
- Click **Properties Window** (not Property Pages)
- Alter the **Virtual path** option from **/MyCompany** to just **/**

Example so you know you're in the right place

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: I don't know how can I miss that.
Thanks!

Comment: Those properties are in a very awkward place, plus the GUI doesn't always display them when you click on the project. Glad it helped.